# How to access custom element from within a linked javascript file?

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element, html5-template

If I had a script like this

```
<template id="x-foo-from-template">
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</template>

<script>
    customElements.define('my-header', class extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
            let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
            const t = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('#x-foo-from-template');
            const instance = t.content.cloneNode(true);
            shadowRoot.appendChild(instance);

            // set up title
            var title = this.getAttribute("title");
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.innerText = title;
            shadowRoot.appendChild(div);
        }
    });
</script>
```

From within `main.js` how can I access the custom element which is equivalent to `this` in the `constructor()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that as explained in [this thread](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/477#issuecomment-205925375): The `currentScript` property will return `null`.

Instead you should load the script outside of the `<template>`, and invoke a function defined in the script from your custom element callbacks `connectedCallback()` or `constructor()`.

Answer (score 0):

You must access `currentScript` outside of the component. I use this:

```
var frag = (document.currentScript||document._currentScript).ownerDocument.querySelector('template').content;
```

I use `(document.currentScript||document._currentScript)` to handle polyfills.

Then in your constructor you would use:

```
const instance = frag.cloneNode(true);
```

At this point `frag` is a `document-fragment` and can contain any number of children. All of these will be replicated by the call to `cloneNode` so that each instance of your Web Component has its own copy of DOM.