# How to access currentScript from shadow DOM (v1)

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom

I want to access current script or shadow root from inside of shadowDOM.

And, final purpose is getting `div.target` element in same shadowDOM.

I try using `document.currentScript`.
However, it returns `null`.
Therefore, I cannot detect where shadowDOM I am in.

Is there a way to do it?

```
<template id="template">
    <div class="target"></div>
    <script>
        // How to access self script element or above element which has target class?

        console.log(document.currentScript)
        // null
    </script>
</template>
<div class="sr"></div>

<script>
document.querySelector(".sr").attachShadow({mode: "open"}).append(
    document.querySelector("#template").content.cloneNode(true)
)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that because of a security or implementation limitation as pointed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45776814/4600982).

To access the Shadow DOM you should use `getRootNode()` as described in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41309731/4600982).